# Unnecessary message above the answer-head

Tags: discussion, bug

When you click on a question to answer it, with no answer on it, you get this message:

[image]

I, however, don't remember seeing this message before. Might be a new change.

But soon after the message disappears. Just as soon as an answer appears.

[image]

**My Question**: What is the need of putting up such a message when the users already know that they can help by answering? And more so, why does the message vanish afterwards?

Comment: Meta.SE: [What is this “Can you help?” message above the answer box?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289217)